# Сортировка массива в лексикографическом порядке по убыванию длины

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, сортировка, arraylist

JAVA

Здравствуйте) В чем заключается моя проблема: у меня есть содержимое текстового файла и мне нужно отсортировать его содержимое в лексикографическом порядке по убыванию длины.

Пример:
армагедон
алфавит
ахаха
ад
а ;
бабочка
бензин
бак
б

Знаю, что существует sort, но он сортирует только в лексикографическом порядке. Может каким-то образом использовать Comparable? Пока его применение мне не особо понятно. Подскажите пожалуйста!

p.s. содержимое файла хранится в листе, без лишних знаков, только слова.

Comment: *мне нужно отсортировать его содержимое в лексикографическом порядке по убыванию длины* Это взаимоисключающие требования. Или лексикографически, или по убыванию длины. Или, скажем. по убыванию длины, а при равенстве длин - в лексикографическом порядке.

Comment: Так, а как мне тогда при равенстве длин в лексикограф. порядке отсортировать? Получается только перебирать буквы?

Comment: Напишите функцию сравнения двух слов, которая сравнит их длины, а при равенстве - сами слова, и вернёт -1, 0 или 1 в зависимости от результата (меньше, равно, больше соответственно). Используйте её как компаратор.

Comment: Хорошо, это я поняла, но как они в лексикограф. порядке то будут расположены.. с использованием компаратора они только по убыванию будут отсортированы.. Не будут ли несовместимы sort и компаратор? Простите, но понять не могу(

Comment: Сортировка - это попарное сравнение и определённые действия в зависимости от результата (например, если больше - обменять местами. если равны или меньше - оставить как есть) При простом sort он тупо сравнивает значения. С компаратором он не сам сравнивает, а передаёт функции-компаратору, и её ответ считает результатом сравнения.

Comment: Спасибо! Все поняла)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
void test() {
    String[] array = {"a", "abba", "b", "baba", "abracadabra"};

    Arrays.sort(array, 
          Comparator.comparing(String::length) // first compare by element length
            .reversed()   // in descending order 
            .thenComparing(Function.identity())); // then comparing by natural, i.e. lexicographically
    
    String[] expected = {"abracadabra", "abba", "baba", "a", "b"};

    assertArrayEquals(expected, array);
}
```

ключевое слово - thenComparing, про которое Вы очевидно не знали, а так, ход мыслей был правильный ;)

Comment: Спасибо! Я уже успела эту сортировку методом "в лоб" так сказать написать)

Answer (score 0):

Я тут написала метод сортировки со своими знаниями java на данный момент,  может кому пригодится)

```
public void fromLargeToSmall () { //список уник.слов в лексикогр.порядке по убыванию длины 
    String[] chars = new String[]{"а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ъ", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я"};
    TreeMap <String, ArrayList<String>> array = new TreeMap<>();

    for (String sym : chars) {
        array.put(sym, new ArrayList());
    }

    for (String symbol : chars) {
        for (String word : listFirst) {
            if (Character.toString(word.charAt(0)).equals(symbol))
                array.get(symbol).add(word);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.get(symbol).size(); i++) {
            for (int j = array.get(symbol).size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (array.get(symbol).get(j - 1).length() < array.get(symbol).get(j).length()) {
                    String temp = array.get(symbol).get(j - 1);
                    array.get(symbol).set(j - 1, array.get(symbol).get(j));
                    array.get(symbol).set(j, temp);
                } } } }

    System.out.println("\n\n-----LIST OF UNIQUE WORDS-----");
    for (String symbol : chars) {
        System.out.println("\n             " + symbol.toUpperCase() + "             ");
         for (int i = 0; i< array.get(symbol).size(); i++) {
             System.out.println(array.get(symbol).get(i));
         }
    }
}
```